# How to get the Last Updated Input Field from the MongoDB with mongoose ( Not last updated document, the updated input field )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern

I got the last updated documents from my mongoDB with

```
Posts.find({}, {}, { sort: { 'updatedAt' : -1 } }).limit(5).exec((err, posts) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: err
        });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        existingPosts: posts
    });
});
```

and this working perfectly fine. But now my requirement is to "**Get the last updated input field of the updated document from mongoDb**".

[Updated Field required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIdWP.png)

I would like to know if there is any way to do it and if so how to do it.
Thank you for your concern and your valueble time.